# Location of text files in android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text-files

I want to read and write some data from text ( .txt ) files in my android project. ( The files are going to be included in the project itself for storing some user preference data )

I want to use only PURE JAVA PROVIDED METHODS to do that, like -
`Scanner myScanner = new Scanner( new File( "file_name.txt" ) );`.

These are a few static data in a non-activity class. So i don't have any `Context` to use for calling `getResources()` or using `SharedPreferences`. And there is no way i can pass a `context` from elsewhere to the class. I'm not going to explain why cause it's going to be a long story. Please don't give any suggestions regarding these ways.

My question is simple - if I want to read/write files with java methods, exactly where do i need to put them in my project?

I AM USING ANDROID STUDIO.

Answer (score 0):

I start with reading a simple text.txt, you first have to upload a file in an asset folder after that you create a Private String method

```
private String readFileFromAssets(String filename) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                getAssets().open(filename)));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        displayMessage("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        displayMessage(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                displayMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

give me a feedback about it.